# If I were named San, and somebody wanted to write out my name with the san honorific, what would it look like?

Tags: names, honorifics

A fiend of mine wants to name a plant San-san, but written correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given as how a Japanese person is unlikely to be named "San", the name itself should be written in Katakana. The "-san" honorific is always written in Hiragana. Therefore:

> **サン**さん
>   **San**-san